# Bootstrap Snippet does not look like it has to in Django

Tags: javascript, css, django, static, datatables

Heyho,

I'm new to Django and I have a problem including a template to my view.
I want to use the following snippet from Bootstrap https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Nj4gp

But it just looks like on the picture below. I took the same code and just changed the content of the table.

[image]

Can somebody tell me what could be wrong? I checked that bootstrap is in the right static folder. I do not understand why some parts work and others not.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it? The image you posted looks pretty similar to the snippet's preview.

Comment: for example the label between pre und next is missing and i forgot to mention that i tried to add a horizontal scrollbar with scrollX : true in JavaScript and it also didnt work :/

Comment: Did you include all the necessary CSS? I believe the labels are in the HTML, too.

Comment: I'm not sure, it is the first time for me working with css, html, JavaScript etc. and i understood it in the way that, when scr or href is a Weblink i do not need to include it to my Project. Is that right? I'm sorry, i must sound  like a stupid, especially because of my bad english :D